# querySkuDetailsAsync is returning empty list with BillingResult code SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing, billingclient

After upgrading the BillingClient to 3.0.0, I started getting about 20% users seeing `SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE` when querying for in-app purchase. The skuDetailsList is also empty. According to the docs, `SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE` implies network is down, but how is the client returning `OK` with the `startConnection` and sending this after trying to query the SKU details? Additionally, I'm seeing a few `ERROR`, which is code 6. Did I have some incorrect implementation or do I just show the user some "An error occurred. Try later" message? I also don't see any warning for any countries in the Play Console or anything that may cause this.

```
BillingClient billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(getContext())
            .enablePendingPurchases()
            .setListener((billingResult, list) -> {})
            .build();

    mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                createSkus(mBillingClient);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {}
    });


private void createSkus(BillingClient billingClient) {
    List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();
    skuList.add("pro");
    SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
    params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
    billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(),
            (billingResult, skuDetailsList) -> {
                // skuDetailsList empty with BillingResult code 2 (SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)

                BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                        .setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList.get(0))
                        .build();
                billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, billingFlowParams);
            });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem where the `BillingServiceDisconnected` code was coming back - my problem was I was calling `BillingClient.startConnection` twice, unfortunately.

Also one more thing to note you need to publish an `Alpha` or `Beta` version of your app with the newly updated library, and if you are using a `applicationSuffix`, remove that before you test it in a debug version.